# How do I make the rightBarButtonItem STAY when a view controller is pushed on?

Tags: iphone, rightbarbuttonitem

When I push a view onto my view controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = 
      [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
}
```

the RIGHT BUTTON ITEM of the navigationController DISAPPEARS.

Is there a way to make the `self.navigationController.rightBarButtonItem` STAY THERE like in the "Notes" application that comes with the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can without using undocumented classes. However, if you set the `rightBarButtonItem` property to an item that looks the same, there shouldn't be a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with

```
self.anotherViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.parentViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
```

after you´ve pushed the ChildViewController